# Как с помощью цикла while() реализовать закрытие программы при вводе определенной команды через Scanner?

Tags: while, scanner

Условие задачи такое:
" После запуска приложение ожидает ввода пути до файла-справочника либо команды на завершение работы (какая-то комбинация клавиш).По команде завершения работы приложение завершает свою работу. После ввода пути до файла-справочника приложение формирует сводную статистику"

Вывод статистики у меня настроен и вызывается с помощью статических методов и отрабатывает хорошо (выводятся отсортированных данные). Пытаюсь задать ввод пути файла через цикл while(). Первая конструкция отрабатывает, но условие if() не работает, когда ввожу в консоль команду exit. Что я делаю не так?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Your File Path Here Or Input exit To End The Program: ");
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String path = input.nextLine();
        List<Address> addresses = UserPathHandler.readFileWithEnds(path);
        StatisticsService.countingDuplicates(addresses);
        StatisticsService.countingFloorInCities(addresses);

        if (input.equals("exit")) {
            System.out.println("Program Close");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так надо проверять введеную строку, а не непонятно что

```
if (path.equals("exit"))
```